# TinyMCE disable text input

Tags: javascript, image, tinymce

I need to create an inline image editor using tinyMCE.

The basic principle has worked very well.

1. Wrap the image with an editable block level element.
2. Disable all buttons other than save and image.
3. Image augmented with a back end connected file manager.

The problem is the user can still type in the 'editable block level element'.

I need to ensure that this particular instance of the editor can only possibly be used to insert and edit a single image tag.

What is the most correct way of dealing with this?

EDIT  --------------  Added code as suggested ---------------

Note that the following is just an tinyMCE init method that restricts the buttons and plugins.  I am not sure that I can do what I want through the Init.

```
tinymce.init({
        selector: ".CMS-image",
        inline: true,
        plugins: [
            "save image filemanager"
        ],
        inline: true,
        toolbar: "image save",
        menubar: false,
        save_enablewhendirty: true,
        save_onsavecallback: function () {
            SaveCMSBlock(this.id)
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you provide your actual code?